# How can you "clone" a conda environment into the root environment?

Tags: python, anaconda, conda

I'd like the root environment of conda to copy all of the packages in another environment.  How can this be done?

Comment: Do you mean "... copy all of the packages **from** another environment" [into root]?

Comment: `conda create --name venv2 --clone venv1`

Answer (score 174, accepted):

There are options to copy dependency names/urls/versions to files.

**Recommendation**

Normally it is safer to work from a new environment rather than changing `root`.  However, consider backing up your existing environments before attempting changes. Verify the desired outcome by testing these commands in a demo environment.  To backup your `root` env for example:

```
λ conda activate root
λ conda env export > environment_root.yml
λ conda list --explicit > spec_file_root.txt
```

**Options**

*Option 1* - YAML file

Within the second environment (e.g. `myenv`), [export names](https://conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html#exporting-the-environment-yml-file)<sup>+</sup> to a yaml file:

```
λ activate myenv
λ conda env export > environment.yml
```

then [update the first environment](https://conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html#updating-an-environment)<sup>+</sup> (e.g. `root`) with the yaml file:

```
λ conda env update --name root --file environment.yml
```

---

*Option 2* - Cloning an environment

Use the [`--clone`](https://conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html#cloning-an-environment) flag to clone environments (see @DevC's post):

```
λ conda create --name myclone --clone root
```

This basically creates a direct copy of an environment.

---

*Option 3* - Spec file

Make a [spec-file](https://conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html#building-identical-conda-environments)<sup>++</sup> to append dependencies from an env (see @Ormetrom):

```
λ activate myenv
λ conda list --explicit > spec_file.txt
λ conda install --name root --file spec_file.txt
```

Alternatively, replicate a new environment (recommended):

```
λ conda create --name myenv2 --file spec_file.txt
```

**See Also**

- [`conda env`](http://conda.pydata.org/docs/commands/env/conda-env.html) for more details on the env sub-commands.
- [Anaconada Navigator](https://docs.continuum.io/anaconda/navigator) desktop program for a more graphical experience.
- [Docs](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/commands.html) on updated commands.  With older conda versions use `activate` (Windows) and `source activate` (Linux/Mac OS).  Newer versions of conda can use `conda activate` (this may require some setup with your shell configuration via `conda init`).
- [Discussion](https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/5253) on keeping `conda env`

---

**Extras**

There appears to be an undocumented `conda run` option to help execute commands in specific environments.

```
# New command
λ conda run --name myenv conda list --explicit > spec_file.txt
```

The latter command is effective at running commands in environments without the activation/deactivation steps.  See the equivalent command below:

```
# Equivalent
λ activate myenv
λ conda list --explicit > spec_file.txt
λ deactivate
```

Note, this is likely an experimental feature, so this may not be appropriate in production until official adoption into the public API.

<sup><sup>+</sup>*Conda docs have changed since the original post; links updated.*</sup>
<sup><sup>++</sup>*Spec-files only work with environments created on the same OS.  Unlike the first two options, spec-files only capture links to conda dependencies; pip dependencies are not included.*</sup>

Comment: This technique seems to only work for packages that were installed with conda or pip, right?  Some packages that were not installed with simple conda or pip package managers don't work.  For example Tensorflow, which was build using Bazel, does not copy over to a new environment via yaml files.

Comment: To overcome the above comment, can one via a bash script copy over environment directory files into the root directory?

Comment: I know this works for `conda`/`pip` packages.  I am unfamiliar with the setup you described.

Comment: This answers the original question you posted.  Your comments reflect another problem.  Perhaps you should edit your question.

Comment: With version 4.4.8, the first line gives >CondaEnvException: Conda Env Exception: Unable to determine environment

Answer (score 97):

To make a copy of your root environment (named `base`), you can use following command; worked for me with Anaconda3-5.0.1:

```
conda create --name <env_name> --clone base
```

you can list all the packages installed in conda environment with following command

```
conda list -n <env_name>
```

Comment: Using this method doesn't install packages in the new environment when installing with anaconda prompt i keeps checking into the cloned environment any solution for that?

Answer (score 14):

When setting up a new environment and I need the packages from the base environment in my new one (which is often the case) I am building in the prompt a identical conda environment by using a spec-file.txt with:

```
conda list --explicit > spec-file.txt
```

The spec-file includes the packages of for example the base environment.

Then using the prompt I install the the packages into the new environment:

```
conda create --name myenv --file spec-file.txt
```

The packages from base are then available in the new environment.

The whole process is describe in the doc:
https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html#building-identical-conda-environments

Comment: This does not copy pip installed packages. Worth noting  I think.

Comment: This is worth noting.
But Spyder says: Don't mix pip and conda
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ul79ihg41Rs 
Could be wise in general.

Answer (score 10):

I also ran into the trouble of cloning an environment onto another machine and wanted to provide an answer.  The key issue I had was addressing errors when the current environment contains development packages which cannot be obtained directly from `conda install` or `pip install`.  For these cases I highly recommend [conda-pack](https://conda.github.io/conda-pack/) (see [this answer](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/a/66754)):

```
pip install conda-pack
```

or,

```
conda install conda-pack
```

then back up the environment, to use the current environment just omit the my_env name,

```
# Pack environment my_env into my_env.tar.gz
$ conda pack -n my_env

# Pack environment my_env into out_name.tar.gz
$ conda pack -n my_env -o out_name.tar.gz

# Pack environment located at an explicit path into my_env.tar.gz
$ conda pack -p /explicit/path/to/my_env
```

and restoring,

```
# Unpack environment into directory `my_env`
$ mkdir -p my_env
$ tar -xzf my_env.tar.gz -C my_env

# Use Python without activating or fixing the prefixes. Most Python
# libraries will work fine, but things that require prefix cleanups
# will fail.
$ ./my_env/bin/python

# Activate the environment. This adds `my_env/bin` to your path
$ source my_env/bin/activate

# Run Python from in the environment
(my_env) $ python

# Cleanup prefixes from in the active environment.
# Note that this command can also be run without activating the environment
# as long as some version of Python is already installed on the machine.
(my_env) $ conda-unpack
```