# How to rename a virtualenv in Python?

Tags: python, directory, virtualenv

I misspelled the name of the `virtualenv` while initializing it using:

```
$ virtualenv vnev
```

I actually intended to create the environment with the name `venv`.
Having tried to rename the `vnev` folder to `venv`, I find that this doesn't provide much help. The name of the activate environment still renames the old `vnev`.

```
$ mv vnev venv
$ . venv/bin/activate
(vnev) $ deactivate
```

I would like to know how to go about renaming the environment?

Comment: Were you able to rename or recreate your virtualenv?

Comment: @andrew No. Atleast, not the way I wanted to. I wrote a script to install all the packages earlier installed in the wrong environment to the new environment.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I move a virtualenv?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32407365/can-i-move-a-virtualenv)

Answer (score 232, accepted):

By default virtualenv does not support the renaming of environments. It is safer to just delete the virtualenv directory and create a new one with the correct name. You can do this by:

1. Activate your virtualenv: `source vnev/bin/activate`
2. Create a requirements.txt of currently installed packages: `pip freeze > requirements.txt`
3. Delete the misspelled virtualenv: `rm -r vnev/`
4. Create a new virtualenv with correct name: `virtualenv venv`
5. Activate new virtualenv: `source venv/bin/activate`
6. Install packages from requirements.txt: `pip install -r requirements.txt`

If recreating is not an option there are 3rd party tools like [virtualenv-mv](https://github.com/brbsix/virtualenv-mv) that might be helpful.

Alternatively you can use [virtualenvwrapper](http://virtualenvwrapper.readthedocs.io/en/latest/command_ref.html?highlight=cpvirtualenv#cpvirtualenv) which provides the `cpvirtualenv` command to copy or rename virtualenvs.

Comment: Is it necessary to deactivate the old virtualenv before deleting it?  I didn't and it still worked but just curious.  Thanks.

Comment: @Bill I believe its best practice but not required. Here is the deactivate script for virtualenv: https://github.com/pypa/virtualenv/blob/master/virtualenv_embedded/activate.sh#L4

Comment: I liked the note on cpvirtualenv

Comment: Does this go for a virtual environment created with pyenv as well?

Comment: So importantly this does not actual move any changes to the virtual environment along, right? Say I change a functon in Scipy it will just install the clean Scipy? (That would defeat the purpose of the virtual envirnoment for me.)

Comment: @Kvothe did you ever find a way to actually moving instead of recreating the virtual environment?

Comment: @jdferreira No I did not.

Answer (score 57):

If you use [virtualenvwrapper](https://virtualenvwrapper.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) this can be done by:

```
$ cpvirtualenv <wrong_name> <correct_name>
$ rmvirtualenv <wrong_name>
```

Also, FYI, to rename a conda virtualenvironment, check out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42231764/how-can-i-rename-a-conda-environment).

Comment: There seems to be a bug with cpvirutalenv, notably in ~/<your_env_dir>/<your_env>/bin/pip and pip3.x is hardcoding paths. And copy done via cpvirtualenv is not updating those. Easy to fix, but without it standard operations like pip freeze or uinstall won't work

Answer (score 19):

The steps I use to rename a virtual environment:

1. Copy the entire virtual environment folder to the new virtual environment.

```
cp -a old_venv new_venv
```

2. Use `sed` within the `new_venv/bin` folder to directly change references to `old_v.env`

```
cd new_venv/bin
# remove cache as sed would otherwise break with the `sed: couldn't edit __pycache__: not a regular file` error
rm -rf __pycache__/
sed -i 's/old_venv/new_venv/g' *
```

3. Remove the old virtual environment

```
rm -rf old_venv
```

Re-installing the ipykernel for jupyter may be required, but otherwise everything seems to work fine

Comment: if you rename the folder containing your old_venv first, you only have to execute step2

Comment: i cannot use this in macOS 12.1. can help?

Comment: It works and is very usefull to fix a simple `mv old_venv new_venv`, but the sed substitution catch too much, and if the old_venv name happen to be in a bin script it produces unexpected results. The substitution should be limited to the shebang initial line. If there is also some problem with sys.path we should prefer [virtualenv-clone](https://github.com/edwardgeorge/virtualenv-clone)

Answer (score 3):

In `windows` I was able to easily rename my virtual environment by editing `activate.bat` inside `scripts\`:

1. Backup the original `activate.bat` (I copy&pasted then renamed mine `BACKUP_activate.bat`).
2. Right-click and edit `activate.bat`.
3. Change `VIRTUAL_ENV` variable from:

   ```
   set VIRTUAL_ENV=C:\some_dir\old_venv_name
   ```

   into

   ```
   set VIRTUAL_ENV=C:\some_dir\new_venv_name
   ```
4. Change `PROMPT` variable from:

   ```
   set PROMPT=(old_venv_name) %PROMPT%
   ```

   into

   ```
   set PROMPT=(new_venv_name) %PROMPT%
   ```
5. Save the edited batch file

NOTE: My solution should work and save `windows users` setting up new virtual environments, I have no knowledge scripting or whatsoever in linux or other operating systems

Comment: There is a little snag with this. The Scripts directory contains a number of .exe files that are placed there when you've created the virtual environment and when installing packages using pip. They have the old path of the virtual environment hard-coded in them. This includes, for instance, pip.exe. You have to modify these files using a hex editor (or use sed on WSL or MINGW).

Answer (score 1):

`cpvirtualenv` from virtualenv-wrapper errored out for me trying to run `virtualenv-clone`, but running that directly worked fine:

```
virtualenv-clone ~/.virtualenvs/oldname ~/.virtualenvs/newname
workon newname
rmvirtualenv oldname
```

No need to reinstall anything.

Answer (score 0):

My answer is similar to creating a new virtual environment with the dependencies of the old one, but this one is succinct.

1. Clone the old environment (say venv_1) to a new environment (say venv_2) using conda.

   ```
   conda create -n venv_2 --clone venv_1
   ```

This creates a new environment venv_2 cloning the venv_1. Hence no separate task of getting the packages/ dependencies. Single step suffices.

2. Delete the old virtual environment. [This step is optional if you still want to keep the old environment]

   ```
   rm -rf "fully qualified path of the old virtual environment"
   ```

So in 1/2 steps the task can be achieved.