# problems creating virtual environments with pipenv

Tags: python, pipenv

I am new using **pipenv** and I would like to know why every time I create a virtual environment, the environment saves me with my username and not with the name of my project folder.

Steps:

1. `cd project-01/`
2. `project-01> pipenv --three`
3. `ls .local/share/virtualenvs/`
4. result: `username-nQve7NT7`

and it always sets me `/home/username/` as the path of my project. I'm using **Xubuntu 18.04.4** with **Python 3.6.9** and **pipenv 2018.11.26**

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend you to take a look at this post

> [How to rename a virtualenv in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43256369/how-to-rename-a-virtualenv-in-python)

hope it helps.

Comment: @adejonghm did it help? Please mark as anwser so the topic can be closed

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem and found that my issue was that there was a `Pipfile` and `Pipfile.lock` in my user directory.

I must have mistakenly run `pipenv shell` there at some point, and while I may have removed the environment folder, the Pipfiles remained.

I imagine pipenv must look up the file tree for a Pipfile and, if it finds one, assumes that is the project root. Removing the Pipfiles fixed the problem for me.