# How to rename venv in macOS 12.1 using sed -i?

Tags: macos, sed, python-venv

I needed to rename a python venv virtual environment in macOS 12.1

I followed the instructions in https://stackoverflow.com/a/68400551

I have already done

`mv old_venv new_venv`

Then

`cd /path/to/new_venv/bin`

Then

`sed -i 's/old_venv/new_venv/g' *`

I get the following error `sed: 1: "Activate.ps1": invalid command code A`

I tried this

`sed -i'.original' 's/old_venv/greendeploy-py3101/g' *` after reading https://stackoverflow.com/a/4247319/80353

Then I get `sed: python: in-place editing only works for regular files`

What is another way to rename venv in macOS 12.1?

I know i can delete and then do a new venv from scratch but i would like to rename where possible.

Comment: sed -i'.original' should work for plain files, but it sounds like you have a directory named "python", and it's (reasonably) refusing to edit that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I solved it

I just realized from the 2nd link i provided in the question there's an alternative to using perl

From https://stackoverflow.com/a/4247319/80353, last line

`perl -i -pe's/old_venv/new_venv/g' *`

So the whole solution is

At the folder level

`mv old_venv new_venv` (no change)

Then

`cd /path/to/new_venv/bin` (no change)

Then

`perl -i -pe's/old_venv/new_venv/g' *` (use this instead of sed)