# changing the project name and environment doesn't work

Tags: python, virtualenv

After my project name was changed, when I activate my environment in my project, it shows activated but doesn't work[image]
in wsl2

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43396657/7976758 You shouldn't rename a virtualenv, you should recreate it. See https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bvirtualenv%5D+rename

Comment: what is `ac`? It isn't clear to me exactly what is going on. What do you mean "my project name was changed"? What exactly did you do?

Comment: as an aside, please **always** use the generic [python] tag for all python related questions. It is 2022. Python 2 is years past it's end of life. There is no need to specify python 3, *python 3 is python*

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Renaming a virtualenv folder without breaking it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6628476/renaming-a-virtualenv-folder-without-breaking-it)

Answer (score -1):

Renaming your project’s directory or environment will break your virtual environment.

Your virtual environment WILL use absolute paths.

The proper solution is **DELETING AND RECREATING THEM**

You can also use the flag `--relocatable`

> virtualenv --relocatable ENV

This flag will make your virtual environment packages relative. But even so, the absolute path is still hardcoded in the activate script.

**TL;DR:** Just delete and recreate them if you ever have to rename them.