# What is the safest way to rename a virtual environment in conda?

Tags: python, virtualenv, miniconda

I've come to realize that there's no simple way to rename a python virtual environment - in conda or otherwise. We created a modified clone of an existing virtual environment (via "conda create -n new_venv ...") to get around some dependency issues, after which we began using the new environment by default. We would like to retire the unused venv and rename new_venv to venv, keeping all of its content intact. What would be the simplest, safest way to do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I rename a conda environment?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42231764/how-can-i-rename-a-conda-environment)