# is it possible to upgrade python version of a conda env and specifically of the base env

Tags: python, anaconda, conda

Suppose I want to

- backup the `base` env by [cloning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42231764/how-can-i-rename-a-conda-environment) it,
- and then upgrade Python version of the `base` env from, say, 3.7.x to 3.10.x.

Is it possible? If it is, how should I proceed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run

```
conda activate base
conda install python=3.10
```

### Important notes

- Even though it is possible, this practice is [not recommended by the official documentation](https://conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-python.html#updating-or-upgrading-python):

> It is not recommended, rather it is preferable to create a new environment. The resolver has to work very hard to determine exactly which packages to upgrade. But it is possible (...)

- Depending on how many packages there are —and how many conflicts—, the procedure might take a long while (after more than 2 hours I quit).
- Console output is quite limited: Although it shows progression while resolving the packages (it took 5 minutes for 444 packages), it does not show progression while resolving the conflicts it has identified, but

  - these words: `Found conflicts! Looking for incompatible packages. This can take several minutes. Press CTRL-C to abort.` (while resolving the conflicts actually took more than 2 hours, before I quit)
  - a spinning cursor,
  - only as many package names as the screen width can hold.