# Can I safely delete the files in "/anaconda3/pkgs"？

Tags: python, macos, installation, package, anaconda

I found the same python package in two different directories on my MacBook. One is in `/anaconda3/pkgs/` and the other is in `/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages`. I wonder what the folder `/anaconda3/pkgs` does and can I delete the duplicate packages in there safely?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it safe to manually delete all files in pkgs folder in anaconda python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56266229/is-it-safe-to-manually-delete-all-files-in-pkgs-folder-in-anaconda-python)

Answer (score 26):

The `pkgs` directory is conda's package cache. I would strongly recommend not to delete packages there manually. Doing so can break environments that use one of these packages.

Instead you can use `conda clean -p` and let conda decide which of the packages are safe to delete.

Comment: Excellent answer because it explains why, and gives an alternate (correct) solution.  If I could give it 2 votes up I would.

Answer (score -1):

Most of the packages that you import in your jupyter notebooks are picked from site-packages.