# Problms of Anaconda with Different versions of numpy

Tags: python, numpy, anaconda

I'm so sorry to bother you with my stupid question. Due to my mismanagement of the anaconda installation package location, I may have used pip and conda to install numpy many times.

But now, after I manually corrected the installation location, numpy1.20.3 was correctly installed in E:\Anaconda\Lib\ site-packages\numpy. It seems that the problem has been solved, but when I opened the Anaconda pkg folder, I found a lot of files related to the 1.15 version of numpy.

I am very curious and want to know whether I can delete these files manually, and only keep the 1.20 version of numpy? I also want to know how these files are generated, are they the undeleted files left when I uninstalled the old version of numpy with conda or pip before?

Hope you won't be bothered by my stupidity.I would be very grateful if you could share some understanding on these issues!

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qiyaq.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SdEgb.png)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it safe to manually delete all files in pkgs folder in anaconda python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56266229/is-it-safe-to-manually-delete-all-files-in-pkgs-folder-in-anaconda-python)

Answer (score 0):

I looked over your problem and it's safe to say that, you can manually delete all the files of the older version of your Numpy (1.15).

Those files are kept by your machine by default, in case you re-install the
particular version for everything to function and works properly.

It had happened to me too, in my case, it was some other module but the same problem.

Comment: thank you for you reply!Your experience is very useful to me