# Why did mamba keep older version of package's files in /pkgs directory upon update to newer version?

Tags: python, conda, mamba, mini-forge, mambaforge

I updated a python package using mamba to a newer version, but I found it kept the files of the older version in the `mamabforge/pkgs` directory. Why would it do this and what is the proper way to update packages so it completely removes the older version?

I was updating the `libcurl` package from 8.2.1 to 8.5.0 on the base mamba environment (yeah, I know altering the base environment is dumb, but I didn't set up this server in the first place and wouldn't have done it this way if I had a choice).

`mamba update libcurl` (the solver came up with upgrading to 8.5.0)

After updating the package, when I run `mamba list` I see `libcurl 8.5.0` listed (and not 8.2.1). When I navigate to `/opt/mambaforge/pkgs/` and list the files in the directory, I see these directories/files listed for `libcurl`:

```
libcurl-8.2.1-hca28451_0
libcurl-8.2.1-hca28451_0.conda
libcurl-8.5.0-hca28451_0
libcurl-8.5.0-hca28451_0.conda
```

Can I safely delete the `libcurl-8.2.1` related directory and .conda file? How do I clean this up?

Answer (score 0):

In viewing this [stackoverflow question related to conda](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56266229/is-it-safe-to-manually-delete-all-files-in-pkgs-folder-in-anaconda-python), I realized that old package files stick around unless you clean them out as the `pkgs` directory is simply a cache. To do this in mamba, I ran this command:

`mamba clean --all`

I then navigated to my `pkgs` directory and listed the contents to see that the old package files and all tarballs were removed. Note that the `--all` flag will clean unused packages, tarballs (`.conda`), lock files, and index cache. If you do not want to remove all of those things, you may want to use [a different flag](https://fig.io/manual/mamba/clean).