# Do separate Anaconda environments install the same package twice, taking up twice the storage?

Tags: python, anaconda, environment

If I have two separate Anaconda Environments, and am installing two packages that are the same in each environment, do they install twice, and take up twice the storage?

i.e.

```
conda create --name myenv1

conda create --name myenv2

conda activate myenv1

conda install matplotlib

deactivate

conda activate myenv2

conda install matplotlib
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why are packages installed rather than just linked to a specific environment?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55566419/why-are-packages-installed-rather-than-just-linked-to-a-specific-environment)

Answer (score 11):

This was a question I had wondered about myself. No it doesn't take up twice the storage. I'm using conda version 4.7.10 in a new ubuntu 18.04 container, but you can try it with your conda version and verify the results.

Environments by default are created in the `envs` folder under the directory you installed anaconda in. For me that is `$HOME/anaconda3`. After each install you want to run `du -sh $HOME/anaconda3/envs` to see a summary of disk space used in human readable format.

```
$ du -sh $HOME/anaconda3/envs
4.0K    /root/anaconda3/envs

$ conda create --name myenv1 -y
$ conda create --name myenv2 -y
$ conda install matplotlib -n myenv1 -y

$ du -sh $HOME/anaconda3/envs
338M    /root/anaconda3/envs


$ conda install matplotlib -n myenv2 -y

$ du -sh $HOME/anaconda3/envs
357M    /root/anaconda3/envs
```

19M more was used, but not double.

Now the question is how do they avoid doubling the space, looking and the envs directory, I don't see any symlinks anywhere. So I looked at some files under myenv2:

```
$ ls -lh /root/anaconda3/envs/myenv2/lib/python3.7/site-packages/matplotlib/mpl-data/fonts/ttf/DejaVuSans-Bold.ttf
-rw-rw-r--. 3 root root 688K Jul  1 06:19 /root/anaconda3/envs/myenv2/lib/python3.7/site-packages/matplotlib/mpl-data/fonts/ttf/DejaVuSans-Bold.ttf
```

The '3' after the permissions and before the file and group owner is the number of hard-links associated with a file. Normally a file has only one. Each environment must create another hard-link to the same file.

Comment: Wow, using hard link is really a better choice than symlinks.

Comment: Great information. If we had the same package of different versions, would that be separate installs? I would think so... Even in the same environment, if you have 2 versions of a package installed that will double the storage (assuming the package versions are the same size).