# Is symlinking packages from base env possible in a virtual conda env (anaconda 3)?

Tags: python-3.x, anaconda, virtualenv, conda, symlink

When creating a new virtual conda env in anaconda, is there a way possible to symlink stuff from the base directory ? 
I tried pip inside the new env, where it had to freshly install python again. I suppose it's a completely new python installation in pip's context.
Is there a way to make the environments non-isolated to symlink stuff make it quick and use less space ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why are packages installed rather than just linked to a specific environment?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55566419/why-are-packages-installed-rather-than-just-linked-to-a-specific-environment). That is Conda already will hardlink packages under-the-hood if you install the same package that is already in any other env (including **base**). You can also use `conda create --clone` to explicitly start an env using another.

Comment: I am on Windows. Yeah it seems so, that most of the stuff is getting hard-linked. I tried finding the disk usage. My conda-env folder occupies 808 MB of space, i individually selected all together the folders in base-env/dir (packages and stuff) that are common between and it occupies 2.84 GB of space.

Comment: But the number of files and folders is larger (64K files,8k folders) when i selected them individually compared to the conda-env which has 20k files and 3.3k folders