# conda create --clone v.s. copying the environment directly

Tags: anaconda, conda

https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html

I understand that

> You can make an exact copy of an environment by creating a clone of
>   it:
>
> `conda create --name myclone --clone myenv`

where `myenv` is an existing environment.

#### How is `conda create --clone` different from copying the environment directory directly into new location?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

[Conda maintains hardlinks to reduce physical disk usage](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55566419/570918). Normal copying will simply make physical duplicates, wasting a bunch of space unnecessarily.

The most problematic issue is that of files that include absolute paths. Copying alone would result in coupling to the original environment in a cryptic way. This could lead to changes in the original environment implicitly affecting the copied one. There is the [`conda-prefix-replacement` tool](https://github.com/conda/conda-prefix-replacement) for use in rewiring these absolute links.<sup>**1**</sup>

Lastly, there are also packages that run post-link installation scripts. Copying wouldn't be running these, which could lead to undefined behavior.

---

<sub>**[1]:** An historical note might be of interest to some - especially for this oh-so-appropriately named piece of software. This tool (`cpr`) arose from a major breakage in Anaconda when MacOS users upgraded to Catalina (10.15) (see [blog post](https://www.anaconda.com/blog/how-to-restore-anaconda-after-macos-catalina-update)). Older installers of Anaconda would sometimes use `/anaconda` as the installation directory, but  Apple made creating folders in system volume root off-limits in MacOS 10.15. This resulted in users' Anaconda installations getting moved during the upgrade, and ultimately breaking them. The `cpr` tool thus provided a mean of resuscitating these incapacitated Conda installations.</sub>

Comment: +1, ran into a bunch of issues when an environment I copied into a new location still had shebangs referring to the original location, and the environment wouldn't work from the new location

Comment: A nightmare in a multiuser cluster every time  somebody wants to install something that requires Conda itself to be updated. I opted for telling my users to do a local installation of miniconda.