# Can we copy packages of one environment to other in anaconda?

Tags: anaconda, package, conda, sharing

I have more than two environments in Anaconda, all three for different purposes. But, I have a few packages like PyTorch which I need to install in all the three environments. But they are too heavy and might consume up to **3 GB** data, which means I will need more than **9 GB** for all 3 environments.

Is there a way to share the packages which when installed in one environment can be utilized or directly be copied to other environments so everything gets done within **3 GB**? Or will I have to download the whole **9 GB(3 GB thrice)** for the 3 environments?

Comment: I don't think it's copied 3 times, but the individual environments are just linking to the package cache in `<anaconda-root>/pkg`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why are packages installed rather than just linked to a specific environment?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55566419/why-are-packages-installed-rather-than-just-linked-to-a-specific-environment) I.e., as long as you "install" the same build that is used in each env, Conda will automatically share it via hardlinking.

Comment: Thanks a lot! But I really don't understand the downloading part, I had to download the packages repeatedly for different environments, any way of solving it?

Comment: @HimaSivaKalyanReddy That’s the point of the question they linked to: Install the package as you normally would in each environment, Conda will not actually download it and duplicate the files if it can avoid it.