# How to manage conda shared environment and local environment?

Tags: python, anaconda, shared-libraries, conda, environment

Say the team has a shared conda environment called 'env1' located at this directory:

```
/home/share/conda/envs/env1/
```

While my working directory is at:

```
/home/my_name/...
```

I do not have write permission for any files under /home/share/, just read permission.
Now I want to use the 'env1' environment with one additional library installed (this library is not originally appearing in /home/share/conda/envs/env1/)
How should I achieve that without re-installing everything in env1 again to my own directory. Also I have to use 'conda install' for that additional package.
I feel that this has something to do with 'conda install --use-local' to handle such shared-local-combined environment situation, but not sure exactly about the procedure.
Thanks for any help and explanation!

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the `--use-local` [flag](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/commands/install.html) only refers to whether conda should install a package built locally and maybe is not distributed through the usual channels (or instead of the usual channels). So I don't think this directly relates to your case.

Perhaps one solution is to [clone](https://conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html#cloning-an-environment) this shared environment into a new one under your own account, where you have write permissions. Then `conda install` the new package you need in that environment. If you are concerned that it takes up space or duplicates the packages, I recommend reading this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55566419/why-are-packages-installed-rather-than-just-linked-to-a-specific-environment), which explains that conda actually tries to not waste space by using hardlinks, so most likely the packages will not actually *re-installed*, but rather reused, in this new environment.

Finally, I'd personally try to create a new environment even just for the reason of clarity. If I later came back to this project, I'd like to know that it requires your "base/shared" env + an additional package. If it's named identically to the shared one, perhaps this difference wouldn't be so obvious.