# Why does the anaconda have duplicated python even if two virtual envs used same python version?

Tags: python, anaconda

I found out that my miniconda directory is over 70GB+ with 10~15 virtual envs.

And I also found that every time I create new envs, it downloads the same python version again, which is almost 2GB, even though it has the same version already...

I think that this is really inefficient for the storage and especially for me, who create a new virtual env every time starting a new Python project.

How do you guys handle the storage problem? I wonder why it does not use something like soft link...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why are packages installed rather than just linked to a specific environment?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55566419/why-are-packages-installed-rather-than-just-linked-to-a-specific-environment) Also, if newer versions are available it could be installing those. Other strategies are using `conda create --clone` to start a new environment with only those found in a previous one, or using the `--offline` flag to force Conda to reuse already cached packages.