# Why are there multiple copies of conda files?

Tags: anaconda, conda, miniconda

I installed Miniconda a while ago, and since then I've noticed there seem several copies of the same files (or files with very similar names) in different locations on my computer.

For example, almost the exact same files in my folder "C:/ProgramData/Miniconda/pkgs" are also in the folder "C:/Users/me/.conda/pkgs". I should note that the only other things in the ".conda" folder is an "environments.txt" file and and "envs" folder with a file called "conda_envs_dir_test".

I've also noticed that the folder "C:/ProgramData/Miniconda/Lib/site-packages" also contains files with very similar names.

Anyway, I wanted to ask if all this is necessary, and why? Sorry if this seems like a weird question. I'm still relativity new to programming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Conda Package Caching

Conda downloads and unpacks packages into a package cache, and then [uses hardlinking](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55566419/570918) to install those packages into environments. One can freely delete the files in the package caches, though this undermines Conda's ability to minimize redundancy across environments going forward. The safest way to clear the package cache is to use the command

```bash
conda clean -tp
```

### Multiple Package Caches

It should be noted that you appear to have two package caches, a system-level cache at `C:/ProgramData/Miniconda/pkgs` and a user-level cache at `C:/Users/me/.conda/pkgs`. This occurs when users install with the "*Install for All Users*" option. This is typically not recommended for regular end users, but rather more for System Administrators who are managing a multi-user installation. Conda functions perfectly (and arguably with less hassle) without ever needing elevated privileges.

All that to say, you may need to elevate your privileges for the `conda clean` command to also clear out the system-level cache. Additionally, if you haven't been using it too long, you may consider uninstalling the system-level install and reinstalling at the user level.

Comment: Thanks a bunch! This is very helpful!