# Anaconda (Miniconda) packages duplicate space

Tags: python, anaconda, miniconda

I just installed Tensorflow and PyTorch on my device using miniconda, and since they are big packages I did expect them to take some space. When I checked using WinDirStat, I noticed that they are taking around 20GB of spaces (cudatoolkits included), and both of them are installed in two places, which seems weird. So, they are both inside the 'pkgs' folder in 'miniconda' directory as well as in the 'site-packages' in each of the environments the libraries are installed. I don't know if I am doing sth wrong, but this doesn't seem OK to me. My question is, is this normal behaviour or am I doing sth wrong? Thank you

Comment: I cannot promise that this is also true on windows but generally conda downloads and installs packages in the `pkgs` folder. The packages in the individual environments have hard links to the `pkgs` folder. AFAIK hard links can confuse tools that count used disk space - just because it says 20G does not mean it actually uses 20G on your HD.

Comment: That actually makes perfect sense. Thank you. I will check that.

Comment: Yeah, I just checked it, around 11GB were actually hard links. Thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why are packages installed rather than just linked to a specific environment?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55566419/why-are-packages-installed-rather-than-just-linked-to-a-specific-environment)