# Does anaconda support hardlink in Windows?

Tags: python, windows, pycharm, anaconda, hardlink

I use anaconda in Windows11 to management conda environments.

However, the environments consume a lot of harddisk, with 20 environment occupying about 50GB.

All environments hold their own hard copy of the packages, which have a lot of repetitions.

Is there any solution to reduce the harddisk usage?

Does anaconda support hardlinks for packages installed like Linux version?

Comment: [It already uses hardlinks by default](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55566419/570918). How are you counting disk usage? Looking at individual folder sizes usually overestimates.

Comment: This link refers to anaconda on linux. I too wonder about symbolic links on Windows to reduce the bloat when using Conda, Miniconda, etc.