# Can I install a Python package in a Conda environment while a script is currently being executed in the environment?

Tags: python, conda, hpc

I used a SLURM manager to submit a bunch of scripts that all run in one Conda environment. I would like to install a new Python package to this environment. Do I need to wait until all of my scripts are done running? Or can I install the package now without messing anything up?

Comment: Hard to say. New install means new constraints for the solver, so it depends whether the install will have to upgrade/downgrade any existing dependencies which the running environment may be using.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Can* you? Sure. *Should* you? No. It could lead to changing existing packages, which could potentially lead to problems (e.g., missing references, API changes) - really depends on how the scripts are written and the dynamics of library loading throughout the scripts.

However, there is a larger issue of *working reproducibly*. May not apply here, but most SLURM users are doing scientific computing and **scientific users should never mutate environments after using them to produce results**. Intact environments are the scientific record and essential for reproducibility. If software requirements change, then create a new environment. [Conda uses hardlinks to minimize disk usage](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55602940/570918), so one should be extremely liberal about creating new environments.

Comment: `so one should be extremely liberal about creating new environments` and `Intact environments are the scientific record and essential for reproducibility` - couldn't agree more -  could only upvote once unfortunately