# How can i use PIL in python?

Tags: python-imaging-library, lib

I have successfully installed Pillow:

chris@MBPvonChristoph sources % python3 -m pip install --upgrade Pillow
Collecting Pillow
Using cached Pillow-9.0.1-1-cp310-cp310-macosx_11_0_arm64.whl (2.7 MB)
Installing collected packages: Pillow
Successfully installed Pillow-9.0.1

but when i try to use it in pycharm got:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/chris/PycharmProjects/pythonProject2/main.py", line 1, in 
from PIL import Image
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PIL'

or using in Blender i got:

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PIL'

I am not a python lib installing pro...so obviously i made something wrong. But how do i fix that?

Maybe i have to say i am working on a M1 Macbook

Answer (score 1, accepted):

looks like you may need to repoint your pycharm to your installed python interpreter.

---

1. go to command line and find out python interpreter path. On windows you can  `where python` in your command line an it will give you where your python and packages are installed.. You could also activate python directly in command line and find paths from there. For example, open command line then;

```
python
```

press enter = activates python

within then you can do:

```
import sys
```

```
for x in sys.path: x
```

---

2. In pycharm make sure you point to path discovered from step 1 and select that to be your python interpreter within pycharm --- check out examples here https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/configuring-python-interpreter.html#add-existing-interpreter

---

3. Should work. Not sure about all the steps you took, but if you installed python with pycharm on top of your regular installation of python i would recommend :

- finding all the paths from step 1
- deleting python using system
- checking if folders found from paths step still exist
- if they do, delete those as well
- start over just with one python installation
- repoint to that in pycharm

Comment: i tried that and i got this from pycharm: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/whDkJ.png

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31840195/invalid-python-sdk-error-while-using-python-3-4-on-pycharm

Answer (score 0):

first

```
pip uninstall PIL
```

after uninstall

```
python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip
python3 -m pip install --upgrade Pillow
```

or

```
brew install Pillow
```

Comment: if i try to uninstall it says "chris@MBPvonChristoph sources % pip uninstall PIL                      
WARNING: Skipping PIL as it is not installed."

Comment: i got the same error message as i stated in my question